# Creating a file in C#

Tags: c#

Hello I am trying to create a file in C# and write some text to it but I get the following error:

> the process cannot access the file C:\Users\W7\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\students.txt because it is being
>   used by another process

```
public void writeFile() {
            string name = @"C:\Users\W7\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\students.txt";
            if (!File.Exists(name))
            {
                File.Create(name);
                StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(name);
                tw.WriteLine("The very first line!");
                tw.Close();
            }   
        }
```

Comment: just remove "File.Create(name);" and read some tutorials please

Comment: Check out the [MSDN StreamWriter page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) for how to use it.

Comment: i would recommend general IO Stream tutorials, because obviously he hasnt understood yet how a Stream works in C#, and i dont think there will be an answer here that explains those completely

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`File.Create` gives you stream, you need to close it if you using same file.

here you don't need to use `File.Create`, `StreamWriter` will create file for you

```
if (!File.Exists(name))
{
    //File.Create(name);
    using(StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(name))
    {
        tw.WriteLine("The very first line!");
    }
}
```

if you using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor you can control append or overwrite by passing `Boolean` value, below will overwrite the file. ( please remove the `File.Exists` condition if you going to overwrite the file, you don't need to check that)

```
using(StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(name, false))
{
    tw.WriteLine("The very first line!");
}
```

Comment: This works but if the file exists it doesn't write anything.What should I do?

Comment: @user3018793 you want to overwrite the file or append to it?

Comment: I want to overwrite it

Comment: `false` to overwrite the file, you get any exceptions?

Comment: No exception only that the file remains unchanged

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code fails is that `File.Create` opens a `FileStream` that isn't closed prior to the `StreamWriter` attempting to do the exact same thing.  Lucky for you, the `File.Create` line is completely unnecessary because creating a `StreamWriter` does that for you.

That being said, there is an easier way to do this:

```
if (!File.Exists(name))
{
    File.WriteAllText(name, "The very first line!" + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Based on comments on @Damith's answer, you only need this line:

```
File.WriteAllText(name, "The very first line!" + Environment.NewLine);
```

Quoting [MSDN File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ,

> Creates a new file, writes the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten

For appending, you'd use this:

```
//assuming file does exist
File.AppendAllText(name, textToAppend);
```

[MSDN File.AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)